# Read request attribute in a Jersey ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: jersey

I've got a Jersey API that's protected by Shibboleth, an SSO implementation. Shibboleth puts  the id of the logged-in user in a request attribute. On the back end, I'm using Shiro for authorization. Shiro would like to know the logged-in user so it can load up permissions.

What is the correct way to get that userId out of the request attribute and into Shiro? Right now, what I'm trying is:

```
@Provider
public final class ShiroLoginFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
        throws IOException {

        final String userId = (String) this.request.getAttribute("nameid");
        final Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        subject.login(new LocusAuthenticationToken(userId));

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, due to [JERSEY-1960](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1960), I can't inject the request context into a filter. Every user needs to "login" in order to load permissions. I'd rather not have to repeat the login code in every method of the API. I am also not permitted to use a web.xml filter (by my boss). Do I have any good option here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should also be able to obtain `ServletRequest` attributes directly from `ContainerRequestContext` via [ContainerRequestContext#getProperty](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) as described in the JavaDoc of the method:

> In a Servlet container, the properties are synchronized with the `ServletRequest` and expose all the attributes available in the `ServletRequest`. Any modifications of the properties are also reflected in the set of properties of the associated `ServletRequest`.

**Note:** Injecting `HttpServletRequest` should work as expected since Jersey 2.4 (released in 10.2013).