# Jersey - get remote address inside ContainerRequestFilter scope

Tags: java, jersey

I was trying to use the code of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724190/how-to-get-the-remote-ip-in-a-containerrequestfilter) and everytime I make a request to the application I get this error:

**HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet api.tienda.venta.ApplicationConfig threw exception**

Stack trace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet api.tienda.venta.ApplicationConfig threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is the code that I'm using:

```
//ApplicationConfig.java

@ApplicationPath("venta")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }

    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(JacksonFeature.class);
        resources.add(RequestFilter.class);
        resources.add(api.tienda.venta.ventaResource.class);
    }

}


// RequestFilter.java 

public class RequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {

      String remoteAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();

      System.out.print("Remote Address: " + remoteAddr);
    }

}
```

If I remove the **@Context** annotation the error is gone and everything works normally, any clue about what is happening here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read request attribute in a Jersey ContainerRequestFilter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691753/read-request-attribute-in-a-jersey-containerrequestfilter)

Comment: I solved this upgrading my jersey libraries.